# HQL Query for Specific Nested Object in a query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I have a Class which has other objects as it's members fields.
e.g.:

```
class Orders{
    private Integer code;
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="code", nullable=false)
    private Category category;
    private PaymentType pt; 
}

class Category{
    private Integer id;
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="id", nullable=false)
    private Brands brand;
    ....
}

class Brands{
    private Integer id;
    private String brandName; 
}
```

I need to get all the Brands for that particular order.

How do I get just the brands through Orders table in Hql?

Answer (score 1):

Are the relations one-to-one? If so, you should be able to query it with:

```
@Query("SELECT FROM Orders orders.category.brand WHERE ...")
Brands findBrandBy(...);
```

if you are using Spring data.

Comment: The relations are mapped many to one, one to one accordingly. And I'm using Spring mvc

Comment: I was thinking of a way where I can use the query in a repo instead of on top of the getter.

Comment: This example is meant to be put in spring repository, my method name might be misleading.

As for many to one relations there shouldn't be any problems, just return List<Brands> from method.